# FOR DO in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just curios can I do this in SQL Server

```
FOR 
    SELECT columns
    FROM table_name 
DO
    ---do some logic
    --proc call
ENDFOR;
```

which means for every record from first select do something in DO block.

This perfectly works for Ingres DB, but not sure if it will work with SQL Server, or I should use only cursor?

Comment: SQL Server has the [while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql).

Comment: @K_foxer9 but this lite different  because you have to set  Sets a condition for the repeated execution of an SQL statement or statement block, however INGRES for do  just  do something  for each returned record without  specifying condition

Comment: There's no `FOR ... DO` in SQL Server - and you should generally try to **avoid** such RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing in a relational database anyway

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support such syntax. So, yes, use the cursor. You can think of it as a (slightly) different syntax compared to Ingres DB. Have a look at various cursor options, though: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options

Answer (score 3):

This Syntax is not supported in SQL Server's T-SQL. But - as you mention yourself in your question - there is `CURSOR`:

```
--Some *mockup* data
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Row 1'),('Row 2'),('Row 3');

--Declare variables to puffer all row's values
DECLARE @WorkingVariable VARCHAR(100);
--never forget the `ORDER BY` if sort order matters!
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT SomeData FROM  @tbl ORDER BY ID; 
OPEN cur;
--a first fetch outside of the loop
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @WorkingVariable

--loop until nothing more to read
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    --Do whatever you like with the value(s) read into your variable(s).
    SELECT @WorkingVariable;

    --Pick the next value
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @WorkingVariable
END

--Don't forget to get rid of the used resources
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

But please keep in mind, that using a loop (however it is coded) is **procedural thinking** and against the principles of **set-based thinking**. There are **very rare situations!** where a `CURSOR` (or any other kind of loop) is the right choice...

Comment: One example where you can't avoid a cursor is when you need to execute a stored procedure for each row of the table.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes, but a *stored procedure* is **procedural thinking** too. Of course there are situations, where this is the right choice, but I've seen tons of SPs which should have been *inline table valued functions* or should have a set-based approach instead of a *RBAR*...  I use a `CURSOR` when statements have to be built dynamically and need `EXEC`...

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't do any behind-the-scenes work for building WHILE loops.
One way to do something like this in SQL Server would look like:

```
declare @indexTable table (fieldIndex bigint identity(1,1), field (whatever your type of field is))

insert into @indexTable(field)
select field
from table_name

declare @pointer bigint = 1
declare @maxIndexValue bigint = (select max(fieldIndex) from @indexTable)
declare @fieldValue (fieldtype)

while @pointer <= @maxIndexValue
BEGIN
select @fieldValue = field from @indexTable where fieldIndex = @pointer
    ---do some logic
    --proc call
set @pointer = @pointer + 1
END
```

This is an alternative to using a cursor to loop over your rowset.

Comment: Please clarify how doing extra work to insert a copy of the data into a temporary table, plus scanning this whole temp table for each row in a loop (your temp table doesn't have any indexes) is better than simply reading each row from the original table one-by-one sequentially by a cursor.

Comment: The original question does mention interest in using a cursor, if you're interested in providing an answer you feel would be more effective.

Comment: @lyrisey That is not "best form" - just merely your opinion. It is, however, a poorly disguised cursor. Worse is the application of a pattern for no real benefit (and a potential performance problem). There is no basis to conclude that this will "run better".